# What can I use to implement a background process for each session in java servlets running on tomcat?

Tags: java, ajax, tomcat, servlets, dojo

I wish to run a function for every user with a session at regular intervals that will check if a user is active. If not active, the function will remove the user from the list of users in the servlet context and clear the user session.

What can I use that will run the function at regular timed intervals for each user?

From what I understand, servletcontextlistener runs only once for the life of the servlet and not for each user so it's not usable. Also, that using threads is advised against in a servlet.

Edit:
Users (using ajax) call a action which contains function that updates a variable I've stored for each user that indicates the last time they contacted the server.

Comment: How will the background thread "check if the user is active"?  You generally won't have a persistent connection to the client, so all you can know is when the client sends a request.  Typically what you are trying to do is accomplished by having the client send periodic heartbeat messages (using AJAX, for example).

Comment: Isn't that what the session lifespan that you can configure already does for you?

Comment: The session will expire but when it expires I would like a function to run to remove the user from variables in the servlet context. I don't know how do to run a function when it expires through session-expire in the web.xml file.

Comment: Please don't spawn another thread. Just listen on session destroy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for `javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener`.
Create one, register it in `web.xml` and have the `sessionDestroyed` do your work.

Comment: Looks promising. I'm going to try to implement it to see if it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways I can think off the top of my head:

1. Use request.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(someValue)
2. Since you're using ajax, instead of sending the "user activity" value you might as well send the actual "kill session" request. This would mean less http calls, since the logic of whether the user is active or not is on the client side, while the actual "session kill" logic is on the backend. So here is the scenario:

   Javascript code runs every minute to check whether the user is active or not (not sure what you're actually looking at, but that's a different story). If after, say, 5 minutes the user hasn't done anything on the client side, then an ajax call is sent to the backend to kill the session.